# Test Methods failing in Prodcopy sandbox(Salesforce)

Tags: salesforce

I have 3 Apex classes in Dev Sandbox and details are given below.

Code coverage after testing.
Case – 79% – 51/64
Lead – 66% – 101/152
Opp – 78% – 221/280

Code deployed to Prodcopy Sandbox along with test class and ran the test class.

Code coverage after running the test class. For some reason code coverage is showing some old data.
Case – 72% – 42/58
Lead – 84% – 131/155
Opp – 85% – 193/226

Code matches between Dev & Prodcopy Sandbox. I am not sure what’s wrong with Prodcopy Sandbox. When I ran the test class on Friday evening 1 test method failed out of 21.(Assertion failure) and it didn’t fail in Dev Sandbox.

Now whenever I ran the test class since Yesterday, 5 test methods are failing with ‘Attempt to de-reference a null object’ in Opp class at same line. Still all 21 test methods are passing in Dev Sandbox.

Please help me.

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: sounds like you are using the `@SeeAllData` annotation and expecting data that is not there in your prod environment.

Comment: @kumarG please share your code which is faield